# UI updates behaving differently in different cases

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch

**Scenario -**  I have labels on my view whose height & width I have aspect fit to superView’s height and width(which denotes that their dimensions are variable and change as per the view.). *I now have to change the label’s properties*. I do so in a function -

```
func ammendViews()
{
    noOfStudentsLbl.layer.masksToBounds = true
    noOfStudentsLbl.layer.cornerRadius = noOfStudentsLbl.frame.height/2
    maleCountLbl.clipsToBounds = true
    maleCountLbl.layer.cornerRadius = maleCountLbl.frame.height/2
    femaleCountLbl.clipsToBounds = true
    femaleCountLbl.layer.cornerRadius = femaleCountLbl.frame.height/2
    
    noOfStudentsLbl.hidden = false
    maleCountLbl.hidden = false
    femaleCountLbl.hidden = false

    
}
```

**Effect 1 -**
[image]

**Effect 2**

[image]

**Case - 1(viewDidLoad() & viewWillAppear())**

I called this function in viewDidLoad() & viewWillAppear() and it had the effect1 .

**Case - 2(viewDidLayoutSubViews())**

I called it in viewDidLayoutSubViews() and the changes appeared as effect1 initially and changed to effect2 after some time.

**Case - 2(dispatch_async)**

And then I put in a mainQueue in async method as -

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.ammendViews()
        }
        
    }
```

And this worked showing effect-2 !!

**My understanding -**
Since my label’s dimension was dynamic and depended upon the main view’s dimension, i.e on device size’s, and when viewWillAppear() and viewDidLoad() are called, the view has not properly been laid so there was just half effect on my label.

On calling in viewDidLayoutSubViews(), the view is already laid so it made the changes, but why was it in effect after disrupting for few secs, I have no idea.

And why did it work all perfect when I put that in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    }
```

Here I was doing asynchronously but in the main thread, So why did it not happen when I did that in mainQueue directly(not asynchronous) in previous 3 cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.  The views are not yet laid out in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.  By placing your code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, Auto Layout has run and the views are laid out properly, so the frames are now set up correctly.  This is the correct place to do this.

In the case of using `dispatch_async`, you are scheduling that code to run on the main thread at a later time.  It just so happens that when iOS gets around to running this code, the subviews have been laid out.  If you put `print`s in your async code and in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, I believe you will find that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will have completed before your async code runs.

Comment: But viewDidLayoutSubviews also has some flaws. I have explained in my question. Why is that ?

Comment: Something odd is going on.  How are you laying out your UI?  Storyboard or in code.  Make sure UI work is done on the main thread.  You might need a `layoutIfNeeded` call if you are laying out your UI in code.